# AngularJS: Migrating http from 1.5.x to 1.6+ with django backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been fumbling with AngularJS for weeks now and trying to cobble together the parts of this, that, and the other thing together to create a file serving web application with a Django backend. I thought things were going well until I found myself trying to upload a file with all of my other form data. My HTML form consistently showed up as having no file attached during the validation step before sending the request. Well, that's no good! Anyways, this ended up being some manner of unsupported operation, for one reason or another.  I turned to `ng-file-upload`, a third party file upload service for AngularJS. The most current iteration of `ng-file-upload` uses AngularJS 1.6 style requests and my third party registration application `angular-django-registration-auth` uses `$http` previous to 1.6.

I need to update the third party registration application but it has the following code.

```
'request': function(args) {
            // Let's retrieve the token from the cookie, if available
            if($cookies.token){
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
            }
            // Continue
            params = args.params || {}
            args = args || {};
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                url = this.API_URL + args.url,
                method = args.method || "GET",
                params = params,
                data = args.data || {};
            // Fire the request, as configured.
            $http({
                url: url,
                withCredentials: this.use_session,
                method: method.toUpperCase(),
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']},
                params: params,
                data: data
            })
            .success(angular.bind(this,function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data, status);
            }))
            .error(angular.bind(this,function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error syncing with: " + url);
                // Set request status
                if(data){
                    data.status = status;
                }
                if(status == 0){
                    if(data == ""){
                        data = {};
                        data['status'] = 0;
                        data['non_field_errors'] = ["Could not connect. Please try again."];
                    }
                    // or if the data is null, then there was a timeout.
                    if(data == null){
                        // Inject a non field error alerting the user
                        // that there's been a timeout error.
                        data = {};
                        data['status'] = 0;
                        data['non_field_errors'] = ["Server timed out. Please try again."];
                    }
                }
                deferred.reject(data, status, headers, config);
            }));
            return deferred.promise;
},
```

Beginning at `var deferred =` (this is defining a promise object, right?) I am unclear on what is going on. The assignments are easy to understand for the most part, with exception granted to the promise object (How does `data = args.data || {};` end up in the right-handside of one of `$http` provider's compound assignment?), but what exactly is happening in the `success` and `error` cases where `angular.bind()` is called? I can't seem to find any good examples where angular seems to bind to a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with then()  calls after finding some decent resources. Here is what my code ended up looking like, I'm including my logging because it may help someone else.

```
"request": function(args) {
// Let"s retrieve the token from the cookie, if available
  if($cookies.get("token")){
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Token " + $cookies.get("token");
  }
// Continue
params = args.params || {};
args = args || {};
var deferred = $q.defer(),
  url = this.API_URL + args.url,
  method = args.method || "GET",
  params = params,
  data = args.data || {};
// Fire the request, as configured.
$http({
  url: url,
  withCredentials: this.use_session,
  method: method.toUpperCase(),
  headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $cookies["csrftoken"]},
  params: params,
  data: data
})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Success case: " + url);
    console.log("Headers: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers(),null, 4));
    console.log("Config: " + response.config);
    console.log("Status: " + response.status);  
    console.log('Response: ');
    console.log('JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4));
    deferred.resolve(response.data, response.status);
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("Error case: " + url);
    console.log("Headers: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers(),null, 4));
    console.log("Config: " + response.config);
    console.log("Status: " + response.status);  
    console.log('Response: ');
    console.log('JSON:' + JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4));

    if(response.data){ response.data.status = status; }
    if(status == 0){
      if(response.data == ""){
        response.data = {};
        response.data["status"] = 0;
        response.data["non_field_errors"] = ["Could not connect. Please try again."];
      }
      if(data == null){
        response.data = {};
        response.data["status"] = 0;
        response.data["non_field_errors"] = ["Server timed out. Please try again."];
      }
    }
    deferred.reject(response.data, response.status, response.headers, response.config);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
},
```